# PhpStorm SCSS - File Watcher Setting

Tags: html, css, phpstorm

I have structure like this:

[image: structure]

Where I am trying to setup SCSS file watcher.

Here are my current options:

[image: settings]

My goal is to compile

`../scss/style.scss` to `../css/style.css`

`../scss/user/profile.scss` to `../css/user/profile.css`

**How to setup my setting in file watcher to achieve this pattern?**

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If it's possible for your project, consider using **compass** to compile your `scss`. By doing it this way, regardless of file structure in `scss` directory, after compilation 
will be this structure mirrored in `css` directory.
It is quite easy to setup, there is also a good guide to read: [PhpStorm / Working with SASS and SCSS in Compass Projects](https://www.jetbrains.com/phpstorm/help/working-with-sass-and-scss-in-compass-projects.html)

Basically you need to:

1. Install compass: `gem install compass`
2. cd to `public\themes\701` directory and run `compass init`, configuration file `config.rb` will be created here, edit this configuration to reflect your directory structure
3. Enable Compass support in settings:

   **File > Setting > Languages & Frameworks > Compass**
4. Now setup File Watcher like in picture:

[image]

`$ProjectFileDir$\public\themes\701` is full path to directory with `config.rb` file.

This will compile `scss` files to `css` directory as requested.